# IronRuby and C++ DLL

Tags: c++, ironruby

I want to call c++ function from dll. Is it possible to use something like DllImport from C# in IronRuby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to do that directly from IronRuby at the moment. You will need to wrap the C++ library with a C# assembly (using P/Invoke) and then use the C# assembly from IronRuby.

Comment: another option is a wrapper using C++/CLI. For automatically generated P/Invoke wrapper see http://www.swig.org/